# Cannot convert type 'SkinnedModel.SkinnedSphere[]' to SkinnedSphere[].An explicit conversion exist

Tags: c#

I have statement like :

```
skinnedSpheres = Content.Load<SkinnedSphere[]>("CollisionSpheres");
```

and here is the definition:

```
 SkinnedSphere[] skinnedSpheres;
```

I tried to cast but it didn't worked.How can I handle this problem?

Comment: You'll need to flesh that code example out a lot more for anyone to say anything definitive. And please remember to _never_ write simply "it didn't work". Be specific. That said, from the error message you quote, it sounds like you may have two different `SkinnedSphere` types running around. Make sure you're using the right one for your `skinnedSpheres` variable. And look into changing one of the type names so that you eliminate the possibility of this confusion in the future.

Comment: Any chance you have two classes named "SkinnedSphere" in different namespaces? Try declaring the skinnedSpheres with the full namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I seems there are two definitions of `SkinnedSphere`, one in the `SkinnedModel` namespace or as a sub class of the `SkinnedModel` class and one in the current namespace or another namespace referenced with `using`.

This is allowed, but will cause collision when using them side by side.